# Merge sort in Scala

Tags: algorithm, sorting, scala, mergesort

I've implemented merge sort in Scala:

```
 object Lunch {

  def doMergeSortExample() = {
    val values:Array[Int] = List(5,11,8,4,2).toArray
   sort(values)
    printArray(values)
  }

  def sort(array:Array[Int]) {
    if (array.length > 1 ){
      var firstArrayLength = (array.length/2)
      var first:Array[Int] = array.slice(0, firstArrayLength)
      var second:Array[Int] = array.slice(firstArrayLength, array.length)
      sort(first)
      sort(second)
      merge(array, first, second)
    }
  }

  def merge(result:Array[Int], first:Array[Int], second:Array[Int]) {
    var i:Int = 0
    var j:Int = 0
    for (k <- 0 until result.length) {
      if(i<first.length && j<second.length){
        if (first(i) < second(j)){
          result(k) = first(i)
          i=i+1
        } else {
          result(k) = second(j)
          j=j+1
        }
      }else if(i>=first.length && j<second.length){
        result(k) = second(j)
        j=j+1
      } else {
        result(k) = first(i)
        i=i+1
      }
    }
  }

  def printArray(array: Array[Int]) = {
    println(array.deep.mkString(", "))
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    doMergeSortExample();
  }

}
```

Could you look at this?  Are there some Scala tricks to do it better, quicker, smaller or cleaner?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just a few unsorted ideas:

- Mergesort can be very nicely expressed using Scala's streams. In particular:

  ```
  def merge(first: Stream[Int], second: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] =
    (first, second) match {
      case (x #:: xs, ys@(y #:: _)) if x <= y   => x #:: merge(xs, ys)
      case (xs, y #:: ys)                       => y #:: merge(xs, ys)
      case (xs, Empty)                          => xs
      case (Empty, ys)                          => ys
    }
  ```

  It'll be slower than working with arrays, but the method is much more
  concise, and it's completely stateless. And, it will be fully lazy - it will
  compute only those elements that you ask for. With such a lazy merge sort,
  you can sort a sequence, then ask only for the first element,
  and you'll get it in *O(n)* time instead of *O(n log n)*.
- Instead of splitting the input into smaller and smaller pieces and then merging them, you can split it into singletons in a single pass and then just merge those singletons. For example, create a `Stream` of `Stream`s like

  ```
  def col2strstr(c: Iterable[Int]): Stream[Stream[Int]] =
    for(x <- c.toStream) yield Stream(x);
  ```

  and then merge pairs of them repeatedly. (Be sure to merge streams with the same or similar length, otherwise the process will be inefficient.)
- This can be further improved: Instead of just splitting the input into singletons, you can split the input into non-decreasing subsequences. For example (using an informal list notation), you'd split `[7,8,9,4,5,6,1,2,3]` into `[[7,8,9],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]]`. This can dramatically reduce the number of merges. In particular, if you pass an already sorted input, it will just check that it's sorted in *O(n)* without doing any merge.
- A further improvement is to look for both non-decreasing and non-increasing sequences (and reverse the non-increasing ones before merging them).

All these ideas can be seen in Haskell's [sort](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3asort) implementation: (Haskell's lists are lazy, just like Scala's `Stream`s.)

```
sort = sortBy compare
sortBy cmp = mergeAll . sequences
  where
    sequences (a:b:xs)
      | a `cmp` b == GT = descending b [a]  xs
      | otherwise       = ascending  b (a:) xs
    sequences xs = [xs]

    descending a as (b:bs)
      | a `cmp` b == GT = descending b (a:as) bs
    descending a as bs  = (a:as): sequences bs

    ascending a as (b:bs)
      | a `cmp` b /= GT = ascending b (\ys -> as (a:ys)) bs
    ascending a as bs   = as [a]: sequences bs

    mergeAll [x] = x
    mergeAll xs  = mergeAll (mergePairs xs)

    mergePairs (a:b:xs) = merge a b: mergePairs xs
    mergePairs xs       = xs

    merge as@(a:as') bs@(b:bs')
      | a `cmp` b == GT = b:merge as  bs'
      | otherwise       = a:merge as' bs
    merge [] bs         = bs
    merge as []         = as
```

Comment: What is the role of @ operator in case (x #:: xs, ys@(y #:: _)) if x <= y   => x #:: merge(xs, ys)

Comment: @ChetanBhasin It's a [pattern binder](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html). If `(y #:: -)` matches, the expression is bound to `ys`.